Proof of limit of $n\tan ({\pi \sqrt{4n^2+1}})$ for natural numbers n
$$n\tan ({\pi \sqrt{4n^2+1}})$$
What does this approach as $n$ tends to $\infty$ when n is a natural number?
I believe it's $\frac{\pi}{4}$ because:
$n\tan ({\pi \sqrt{4n^2+1}}) = n\tan ({\pi (\sqrt{4n^2+1}}-2n)) $
$\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n $ is small so
$n\tan ({\pi (\sqrt{4n^2+1}}-2n))$ approaches $n\pi (\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n)$
$n\pi (\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n) =n\frac{\pi} {(\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n) }$
$$n\frac{\pi} {(\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n) } = \frac{\pi} {(\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n^2}}+2) }$$
Which approaches $\frac{\pi}{4}$

This is basically right. You can't say "$f(n)$ approaches $g(n)$ as $n\to\infty.$" "Approaches" implies a limit, which is not a function of $n.$ What you want to say is $\tan(x)/x\to1$ as $x\to0.$

Then you want to show $\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n\to0$ as $n\to\infty.$ Using the word "small" is not clear enough.

Compare with this problem.

Following Thomas, one more hint: $\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n=2n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{4n^2}}-1\right)\sim2n\frac1{8n^2}$ where $a\sim b$ means $a/b\to1$.

I tried Stolz-Cesaro without success. Introducing the $2\pi n$ term and then using angle-addition also doesn't work, since it immediately vanishes. $\mathbb{N}$ is needed, else the limit fails to exist in $\mathbb{R}$. Neat little problem!

As initially commented, your arguments are fine but two of them need a more rigorous rewriting:
$$\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n=\frac1{\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n}\sim\frac1{4n}$$
where $a\sim b$ means $\frac ab\to1$ (here: as $n\to\infty$).
Since moreover $\tan x\sim x$ as $x\to0$, we derive
$$n\tan(\pi(\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n))\sim 
n\pi(\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n)\sim n\pi
\frac1{4n}=\frac\pi4,$$
and we are done.

By another way we have
$$\pi \sqrt{4n^2+1}=2\pi n\left(1+\frac1{4n^2}\right)^{\frac12}= 2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4n}+O(1/n^2)$$
then
$$n\tan ({\pi \sqrt{4n^2+1}})=\frac{\pi}{4}+O(1/n)\to \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Equivalently we can use binomial approximation.
